# WebInvoke POST request only works if I write the url manually

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

```
public async Task<string> insert(string x, string y, string z)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {         
        var payload = new rootnode { username = x, userpassword = y, usermobile = z };
        var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
        var entry = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entry);
        var result = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:20968/Service1.svc/insert/", entry);
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();               
    }
}
```

My function is working very well only if I write the url manually with entry=""

```
client.PostAsync("http://localhost:20968/Service1.svc/insert/x,y,z", "entry");
```

Here is my webget method also

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "insert/{username}/{userpassword}/{usermobile}")]
```

Comment: it works only if i set entry="", and url like this  "http://localhost:20968/Service1.svc/insert/x/y/z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the stated uri template in the OP you are constructing the request wrong. It was already indicated that it worked when the uri was manually constructed. repeat the same construction when sending the request.

Not enough details was provided about the target web method so the following example assumes that with something like...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "insert/{username}/{userpassword}/{usermobile}")]
    InsertResponse Insert(string username, string userpassword, string usermobile);
}
```

Calling the service could look like this by constructing the request manually

```
public async Task<string> insert(string x, string y, string z) {
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:20968/Service1.svc/");

        //UriTemplate = "insert/{username}/{userpassword}/{usermobile}"
        var url = string.Format("insert/{0}/{1}/{2}", x, y, z);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(request);

        var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes sure but shouldnot i have to serialize the objects and send them?using JsonConvert.SerializeObject for security issues? and what if i have many parameters to send?suppose that i have a query with multiple joins, thanks already